# accumulating terminal profiles

Tags: terminal, bash, login-items, perl

I have a "login item" which runs a short Perl script. It is a `*.terminal` file simply because I don't know how else to run a script as a login item (ie. there is no input or output). It works well, except for one thing: each time it runs, it creates a new copy of the Terminal profile. By now, I have about a hundred of them :-(

This doesn't seem to happen with my other `*.terminal` files, but there are two key differences and I don't know which one is responsible for the behavior:

1. The others are not login items, I run them manually by double-clicking their icons.
2. The others are bash scripts, not Perl scripts.

How can I prevent these new profiles? Again, I'm not married to Terminal - if there is a way to run a script at login time that doesn't involve Terminal, I prefer it.

--
Ian

Comment: What do you mean with Terminal profile?

Comment: @nohillside when you open the Preferences dialog in Terminal.app, you get to select among various "profiles", and you can create new ones. It's like a theme, but not only for UI but other settings as well.

Comment: Ah, right. I assume the perl script starts with `#!/usr/bin/perl` or similar? Do things change when you create a bash script instead which then only runs `exec /path/to/perl/script`? Also, is there anything in the Perl script which interacts with Terminal?

Comment: The script starts with `#! /usr/bin/env perl` . Does nothing at all interactive. It's something I would do in a cron job if the Mac had a working/maintained cron :-P I haven't yet tried the bash oneliner angle but that is next, hopefully today.

Comment: Cron still works :-)

Comment: Yes and no. There is nothing like `anacron` on Linux or *BSD, so no way to run stuff "daily" if you turn the computer off when not in use. (Even `launchd` will not run jobs that missed their turn that way.) Anyway, I found a workaround for my specific problem - see the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I worked around this by dropping Terminal.app from the picture entirely, something I already wanted to do even before. I created a fake Application with the Automator and put the Application into my Login Items. Before today, I didn't know this was possible - I had only created the other types of artifacts with Automator, and those can't be run standalone like this.